# R: Conditionally select rows based on ther value and the average value of the rest rows with same key

Tags: r, grouping, subset

This should be very simple but I can't figure out how to do It properly.
Given the following example dataframe:

```
telar <- data.frame(name=c("uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco"), id=c(1,2,3,1,2), test=c(10,11,12,13,14))

telar
    name id test
1    uno  1   10
2    dos  2   11
3   tres  3   12
4 cuatro  1   13
5  cinco  2   14
```

I am trying to select all the rows that, for example, have a value of test that is bellow the average of al the values in the dataframe telar that have the same id value.

I have already properly grouped the values by id and computed their average like this, but I do not know how to perform the comparison.

```
> summarise(group_by(telar, id), test=mean(test))
A tibble: 3 x 2
 id  test
<dbl> <dbl>
1     1  11.5
2     2  12.5
3     3  12
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create your groups and keep the values that are less than the mean, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

telar %>% 
 group_by(name, id) %>% 
 filter(test < mean(test)) %>% 
 ungroup()
```

Comment: My solution is the same, and for big tables adding ungroup() is good idea
```telar %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(test < mean(test)) %>% 
  ungroup()```

Comment: Should ungroup() always be run after a group_by() action in order to leave the dataframe as it was before?

Comment: Sure. It is always a good idea If you are done with group calculations.

Answer (score 0):

There is undoubtedly a way to do this without using data.table, but I offer it as a solution

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(telar)
telar[, avg := mean(test), by = id][test < avg]
```

note I recommend if you're doing further analysis in data.frame after this, I recommend to return to a data.frame using `setDF(telar)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`, this can be done with `ave`

```
telar[with(telar, test < ave(test, id, name)),]
```